# Need help understanding Bernoulli standard deviation

Tags: mathematical-statistics, standard-deviation

I'm looking at the solution of a homework problem from a class I took many years ago and I'm not understanding how they calculated standard deviation (see question 1C here:  http://datasciencelabs.github.io/2016/pages/html/hw2-problems.html).  In the roulette game, a player wins a dollar with a probability of 18/38, and loses a dollar with a probability of 20/38, the solution to 1C says that the standard deviation is:

|1 --1|*sqrt((9/19) * (10/19))

Where does the |1 --1| come from?  I recognize the rest of the formula as sqrt(p*(1-p)) which I believe is the standard deviation of the Bernoulli distribution (please correct me if I am wrong).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At Problem 2E on that link is the formula $|a-b|\sqrt{p(1-p)}$, which is the standard deviation when you win $a$ with probability $p$ and $b$ with probability $(1-p)$. If you're asking about the vertical bars, that's the absolute value; the difference  between winning and losing. You have the case with $a=1$ and $b=-1$

As you suggest, the second half is the Bernoulli standard deviation. In a Bernoulli distribution you get 1 success with probability $p$ and 0 with probability $1-p$, so the term out the front is $|1-0|$.  If you win 1 or lose 1 (ie,  win $-1$), the difference between winning and losing is  2 rather than just  1, so the standard deviation is  the  Bernoulli standard deviation multiplied by 2.